# How to keep a 2 column text flowing top down after a column-spanning-paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph

My column-spanning-paragraph breaks the desired text flow. This illustration probably makes it clear. How can I force the text to flow from left-top to bottom to right-top to bottom?

The page is ONE text-frame. I would like to keep it this way since it makes it easy to keep the different elements aligned when I insert content before or after.

[image: Current and desired flow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each item is a separate text box, you use the text tool to link them in that order manually at the text outflow and inflow boxes.

Comment: I would like to avoid separate text boxes so that my text keeps aligned when I change the contents.

Comment: You could create a separate text box for the pull quote and put text wrap on it so that it forces the text away at top and bottom, but honestly I think you're putting too many requirements on this. Some of it may have to be manually aligned after it's laid out.

Comment: Thanks, then this is the correct answer. I have to create new text boxes for my desired alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can not accomplish your "desired" image with a single text box due to the text flowing vertical, then to the second column. With a single text frame the only possibility is the "current" image.

You could accomplish your desired flow by using two text boxes and **anchoring** the text box for your internal headline to the column text, with the appropriate text wrap.